# How to make Meteorjs autoform multilingual?

Tags: meteor, multilingual, meteor-autoform, meteor-collections

im trying build a multilingual website, but when using autoform meteorjs render a name of subdocument as title, and need to use as multilingual.

Is nice to use with multilingual template: https://atmospherejs.com/fameteor/lang
and im reading about using de extension:
https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n-db,
but dont understand if this is the good option, because the examples talk about other things.

thanks,

Comment: Is nice to use with multilingual template: https://atmospherejs.com/fameteor/lang is the most simple package for simple variables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple as use the extension for meteor-autoform package named: gwendall/meteor-autoform-i18n
thanks for read my question.
bye.

Comment: autoform is very powerfoul package with this extension have complete tool.